# Python MySQLdb not refreshing database information

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-python, irc

I'm currently codiing a simple IRC moderator/utility bot. I plan to have a web interface that will easily update command data and whether or not the command is enable using a MySQL database to store most of the information. It is able to connect to the database and retrieve the data correctly. However after I change a value in the database it does not update. I have tried to use `.close()` and `.commit()` or enabling auto commit (even though im not changing anything in the database) as solutions from others who have had this problem before.

```
import socket
import StringIO
import MySQLdb

ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = "irc.twitch.tv"
channel = "#jusjoe99"
botName = "N0tABot"
oauth = ""
twitter = {"msg": "Check me out on me out on my Twitter to stay up to date and see when ill be live next! twitter.com/jusjoe99", "enabled": True}
youtube = {"msg": "Check me out on me out on the YouTubes, I dint post much but I plan to eventually doing some vids! youtube.com/jusjoe99", "enabled": True}
game = {"msg": "", "enabled":False}
resourcePack = {"msg":"", "enabled":False}
data = []
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user="myBot",passwd = "wHZ4VCWe2jaYxH9y",db = "mybot")
db.autocommit(True)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM commands")
data = cursor.fetchall()
db.commit()
cursor.close()
db.close()

def MySQL():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "localhost",user="myBot",passwd = "wHZ4VCWe2jaYxH9y",db = "mybot")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM commands")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()

def ping():
    ircsock.send("PONG : Pong\n")

def joinChannel(chan):
    ircsock.send("JOIN " + chan +"\n")

def sendMessage(chan, msg):
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG " + chan + " :" + msg + "\n")

def hello():
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :Hello\n")

def start():
    ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
    ircsock.send("PASS " + oauth + "\r\n")
    ircsock.send("USER "+ botName + botName + botName + "\r\n")
    ircsock.send("NICK " + botName + "\r\n")
    joinChannel(channel)
    updateValues()

def getSong():
    song = open("cur_song.txt","r")
    cursong = song.read()
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + "The Current song is: " + cursong + "\n")
    song.close()

def updateValues():
    MySQL()
    checkTwitter()
    checkYouTube()
    checkGame()
    checkResourcePack()

def checkTwitter():
    twit = data[2]
    print twit[1]
    twitter["enabled"] = twit[1]

def checkGame():
    gme = data[0]
    game["msg"] = gme[2]
    if gme[1] == 0:
        game["enabled"] = False
    else:
        game["enabled"] = True

def checkResourcePack():
    rp = data[1]
    resourcePack["msg"] = rp[2]
    if rp[1] == 0:
        resourcePack["enabled"] = False
    else:
        resourcePack["enabled"] = True

def checkYouTube():
    ytube = data[3]
    if ytube[1] == 0:
        youtube["enabled"] = True
    else:
        youtube["enabled"] = False

start()


while 1:
    ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)
    ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r')
    print ircmsg
    updateValues()
    if ircmsg.find(":!song") !=-1:
        getSong()
    if ircmsg.find(":!twitter") !=-1 and twitter["enabled"]:
        sendMessage(channel, twitter["msg"])
    if ircmsg.find("PING :") != -1:
        ping()
    if ircmsg.find(":!youtube") !=-1 and youtube["enabled"]:
        sendMessage(channel, youtube["msg"])
    if ircmsg.find("!tp") !=-1 and resourcePack["enabled"]:
        sendMessage(channel, resourcePack["msg"])
```

Thank you for your help!(And i am sorry for the messiness of my code)

Comment: well you connect to MySQLdb while initiating script and saving `data`. You are creating global variable which is available everywhere. When you call MySQL() in updateValues(), you are creating *local variable* inside that function, which **does not** overwrite global "data". You need to tell python it's global variable. add `global data` into MySQL function, prefferably as a first line.

Comment: @kecer Thank you so much! I feel stupid that i looked that over.